# is there "Self-Service site creation" settings in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, administration, self-service

I am working on a SharePoint online tenant, and i am trying to find where i can configure the Self-Service Site Creation setting, which we use to have inside our on-premises farms, as follow:-

[image]

so is this option still available in sharepoint online? if yes then how i can access it, as in sharepoint online i can not access the web application..

Answer (score 2):

Their is option under the SharePoint Admin center > Settings options:

- Admin centers > SharePoint.
- Click settings.
- Under Site Creation, select to show or hide the Create site command.
- If you select Show the Create site command to users who have
  permission to create sites, specify the type of site that users can
  create.[image]

[Manage site creation in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-creation-in-SharePoint-Online-e72844a3-0171-47c9-befb-e98b23e2dcf9)

Comment: thanks for the reply and clarification.. but if i chose the second option "Show the create site command to users...." then from where users can create sites? i mean where the link to create sites can be found?

Comment: Create site command is on the SharePoint Home page...https://ursite url/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx

Comment: i am not sure what is going on exactly, now i set the site creation option to be "Hide the Create site command ",, but when i access the `url/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx ` using non-admin user, the non-admin user can see the "+ create site " & "+create post" links... so not sure why the links did not get hidden !!

Comment: can you please advice on my above comment?

Comment: I know this is old but might help others.  After making any Setting changes you will have to wait up to 24 hours for these changes to reflect.